# Вывод данных из таблицы mysql pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код который выводит данные из таблицы с помощью цикла:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
    $db   = '';
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id_t = ".$_GET['id']."");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<div style='margin-left:77%;margin-top:2%;border-radius:10px;color:#777777;width:300px;height:auto;background:#fff;display: inline-block;'>
    <center><p style='font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;margin-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;'>Информация о процессе</p></center>
    <table style='margin-top: -10px;margin-left:10px;'>
    <tr>
    <td style='font-size: 16px;color: #393939;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:10px;'>Номер процесса:</td>
    <td style='font-size: 16px;color: #393939;padding-bottom:10px;'>".$row['id_t']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style='font-size: 16px;color: #393939;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:10px;'>Процесс:</td>
    <td style='font-size: 16px;color: #393939;padding-bottom:10px;'>".$row['process_t']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style='font-size: 16px;color: #393939;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:10px;'>Статус:</td>
    <td style='font-size: 16px;color: #393939;padding-bottom:10px;'><input style='width:100px;height:auto;border:0px;font-size:16px;color: #393939;' type='text' value='".$row['status_t']."'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style='font-size: 16px;color: #393939;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:10px;'>Клиент:</td>";
}
?>
```

Как вывести данные без цикла?

Comment: А от нас вопрос - зачем?

Comment: @u_mulder я думаю если мы выводим данные только одной записи будет правильнее, но это не точно)

Comment: Ну так и вызовите `fetch` __один раз__: `$row = $stmt->fetch();`

Comment: @u_mulder хорошо, спасибо.